# Visual Studio very slow after connecting to Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We started a new Repository in Visual Studio Online. Upon connecting to it, our whole team's Visual Studio 2015 crashes intermittently.

We've checked the traffic in Fiddler and this is what constantly hits:

{Guid}.vssps.visualstudio.com:443
 and 
vortex.data.microsoft.com:443

Where {Guid} is (I'm guessing) specific to our server.

Why is Visual Studio constantly hitting these sites while we're working? 
We're using TFS as our source control and we do have exclusive locks activated, but surely once it's locked the files it shouldn't need to communicate to the server until we action it to do something?

We've spoken to our network admins and they say this should not be a problem.

Can anyone give us any recommendations please?

Comment: Did VS 2015 ever work before?  Does it work with other VSO repositories?  How was it configured before?  Did you look in the Event Viewer logs on the affected machines?  What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: VS2015 worked fine before - We were running a locally hosted TFS repo. I do see some errors in Event Viewer. The first I get is : Error Handler Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).

Comment: Are you able to get any data from the repo, or does it generate the error while connecting?

Comment: Can you try with this plugin: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51e11ccc-6334-4873-912d-bf5025eb115d to see if VS works correctly with this source control provider?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. We can connect to the repo, we can branch/merge, get latest etc. It's while we're working that it just freezes up and sometimes it recovers and other times it just crashes. That plugin seems to be for Git, we're using TFS as our source control. That log in the Event Viewer makes me think that it is with our networking infrastructure. It seems as though Visual Studio constantly communicates with the repo server and something there is being blocked. I'm sure this is the case since before we moved our Repo from local to cloud based, we never encountered these issues.

Comment: Does VS works correctly if disconnect from the VSO Project?